# How would one create a codeception assertion to see a copyright symbol?

Tags: php, codeception

I am attempting to create an acceptance tests which looks for a line of text that also contains a copyright symbol `(c)`.  I have tried using:

```
$I->see('&copy; 2016 MyCompany, LLC');
```

Using an html escape character with the assertion fails. Any tips on how to make codeception see the copyright symbol?

Comment: $I->see('&copy; 2016 ********** Company, LLC');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`see` method matches decoded html entities, so you have to use the actual character as advised by Sammitch.

The alternative way is to use [seeInSource](http://codeception.com/docs/modules/PhpBrowser#seeInSource) method and match the entity as it is in the HTML:

`$I->seeInSource('&copy; 2016 MyCompany, LLC');`

Update: I checked the edit history and it appears that you used the actual © character in original question.

I did a quick test and `$I->see('© 2016 MyCompany, LLC')` matched both © and `&copy;`, so it should be working for you. Make sure that your test file is saved as UTF-8 and your website is using UTF-8.
If you use a different charset, use character codes in assertion.

Comment: Thank you very much. This helped alot.

Answer (score 1):

The copyright symbol does not occur in the 7-bit-safe subset of ASCII shared by most multibyte encodings and will therefore be represented by varying byte sequences depending on the encoding used. You need to determine what encoding your expected output will be in, and then tailor your assertion string to match.

For UTF-8:

```
$I->see('\xc2\xa9 2016 MyCompany, LLC');  // PHP<7
$I->see('\u{a9} 2016 MyCompany, LLC');    // PHP>=7
```

For ISO-8859-1:

```
$I->see('\xa9 2016 MyCompany, LLC');
```

Also, using literal byte sequences like this help you avoid the problem of copy/pasting data between programs using different encodings. What looks valid in ISO-8859-1 is totally borked when you paste it into a UTF-8 document, and vice versa.

**Note:** The copyright symbol occurs within a narrow window of UTF-8 sequences [U+80 through U+BF] where the Extended-ASCII/Windows-1252/ISO-8859-1 single-byte representation matches the second byte of the two-byte UTF-8 sequence. This is because UTF-8 reserves the first two bits of "trailing bytes" which are always 10, which makes the first nibble 10XX, hence 0x80 through 0xBF.

I felt the need to add this in as I've recently had a very protracted argument with someone regarding the "garbage byte" when trying to explain their encoding mismatch. See [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) for more info on UTF-8 encoding.